# Package or Way to open an email attachment from within R

Tags: r, curl, gmail

I've been having a difficult time finding a way to open an email attachment from *within* R (and specifically in my case, an email from a Gmail account). What I mean by this is that I want to be able to authenticate a gmail session from within R (much like you would authenticate a Google Docs session using Duncan Temple Lang's `RGoogleDocs`package), then save an email object to a variable, and then extract the file from that instance to a data frame - In my specific case, the attachment in question is simply a csv file, so assume here that the file type can be extracted easily to a data frame.

I make pretty ample use of the `sendmailR` package to do the opposite, i.e. send an email from R to an email account, but have had no luck opening an email from within R, and a lot of searching on Google has not yielded anything for me.

Does anyone know of a package designed for this or way to do this with say `RCurl`?

Comment: you might have better luck searching/asking for how to do this using cURL or in general through a shell and then seeing if you could adapt that to R

Comment: This gets you part of the way there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241812/how-can-i-send-receive-smtp-pop3-email-using-r