# Send email from R using "sendmailR" with more than 1 attachments

Tags: r, sendmailr

I am using `sendmailR` to send emails from R. Does any one know what needs to be used to be able to attach more than one file?

This is the code that I have been using for a single attachment, but I don’t know how to adjust it for more than one file:

```r
library(sendmailR)

from <- "......org"
to <- c("Pegah@...net")
subject <- "Daily Report"
body <- "Attached is today's Daily Report"

mailControl = list(smtpServer=".....net")
attachmentPath <- paste0("/Rate and Lab Counts ", Sys.Date(), ".png")
attachmentObject <- mime_part(x=attachmentPath, name=attachmentName)
bodyWithAttachment <- list(body,attachmentObject)

sendmail(from=from, to=to, subject=subject, msg=bodyWithAttachment, control=mailControl)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sendmailr` supports multiple attachments; see if this solves your problem (e.g. ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/14376117/12957340):

```
library(sendmailR)
from <- "......org"
to <- c("Pegah@...net")
subject <- "Daily Report"
body <- "Attached is today's Daily Report"
mailControl=list(smtpServer=".....net")
attachmentPath_1 <- paste0("/Rate and Lab Counts ", Sys.Date(), ".png")
attachmentPath_2 <- paste0("/Percent change over time ", Sys.Date(), ".png")
attachmentPath_etc <- paste0("/Frequency trend data etc ", Sys.Date(), ".png")
attachmentObject_1 <- mime_part(x=attachmentPath_1, name=attachmentName_1)
attachmentObject_2 <- mime_part(x=attachmentPath_2, name=attachmentName_2)
attachmentObject_etc <- mime_part(x=attachmentPath_etc, name=attachmentName_3)
bodyWithAttachment <- list(body, attachmentObject_1, attachmentObject_2, attachmentObject_etc)
sendmail(from=from, to=to, subject=subject, msg=bodyWithAttachment, control=mailControl)
```